# Python RegEx - Negative Lookahead not working after a ? quantifier

Tags: python, regex

I'm new to regex, and I'm wanting to find all instances of "po" and it's variants (i.e. "p.o. | p. o. | p o") that ISN'T followed by "box" because I'm interested in purchase orders and not PO boxes. The code below isn't working and just matches the po even when it's followed by a "box." Any ideas?

```
string = " po  pobox  po box  po  box    p.o.  p.o.box  p.o. box  p.o.  box"

re.findall(r' p\.?\s?o\.?(?!\s*box)', string)

//expected output
[' po', ' p.o.']

//actual output
[' po', ' p.o.', ' p.o', ' p.o', ' p.o']
```

Comment: The `p.o` in `p.o.box` is not followed by `box`. It's followed by `.`.

Comment: Are you referring to the expected output part? It was suppose to read “p.o.” instead of “p.o” so box WOULD follow “p.o.”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You placed the lookahead after an optional pattern and backtracking makes it possible to match the string in another way.

If Python supported possessive quantifiers, it would be easy to solve by adding `+` after the `\.?` that is before the lookahead: [`p\.?\s?o\.?+(?!\s*box)`](https://regex101.com/r/vJ61uO/1). It would prevent the engine from backtracking into `\.?` pattern.

However, since Python `re` does not support them, you need to move the lookahead right after the `o`, obligatory part, and add `\.?` to the lookahead:

```
r'p\.?\s?o(?!\.?\s*box)\.?'
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oGdWsE/1). Add `\b` after `box` if you plan to match it as a whole word. Same with the first `p`, you may want to add a `\b` before it to match `p` as a whole word.

**Details**

- `p` - a `p`
- `\.?` - an optional (1 or 0) dots
- `\s?` - an optional (1 or 0) whitespaces
- `o` - an `o`
- `(?!\.?\s*box)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location there  is an optional dot, 0+ whitespaces and `box`
- `\.?` - an optional (1 or 0) dots

Comment: That’s exactly what the issue was! I thought my overalll expression was right, it was just that backtracking issue causing the false positives. But now, the last period is chopped off. Is there a way to get it to still show if it’s there?

Comment: Nevermind! I missed the “\.?” at the end. That took care of that! Thanks again!